# How do you fix: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'player'"?

Tags: pygame, python-3.7

I am making a platformer game that has moving platforms. I have a class where there are parameters to create a moving platform. I then put it all into an array and finally draw them in a for loop. However, I keep getting this error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'player'".

```
class MovingPlatform(Platform):

    def __init__(self, sprite_sheet_data, change_x, change_y, x, y, 
                 boundary_top, boundary_bottom, boundary_left, 
                 boundary_right):

        super().__init__(sprite_sheet_data)

        self.change_x = change_x
        self.change_y = change_y

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.boundary_top = boundary_top
        self.boundary_bottom = boundary_bottom
        self.boundary_left = boundary_left
        self.boundary_right = boundary_right

        self.player = None

        self.level = None

class Level(object):

     def __init__(self, player):
        self.platform_list = None
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player

    def update(self):
        self.platform_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.platform_list.draw(screen)


class Level01(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):

        Level.__init__(self, player)

        level_moving_blocks = 
        [[MovingPlatform(STONE_PLATFORM_MIDDLE, 1, 0, 1350, 280, 0, 
          0, 1350, 1600)], 
         [MovingPlatform(STONE_PLATFORM_MIDDLE, 0, 1, 2000, 400, 
          300, 500, 0, 0)]
        ]

        for block in level_moving_blocks:
            block.player = self.player
            block.level = self
            self.platform_list.add(block)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/qingduliu/PycharmProjects/Platformer/Video Game.py", 
line 672, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/qingduliu/PycharmProjects/Platformer/Video Game.py", 
line 591, in main
    level_list = [Level01(player)]
  File "/Users/qingduliu/PycharmProjects/Platformer/Video Game.py", 
line 374, in __init__
    block.player = self.player
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'player'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list has lists inside of it. In other words the list nesting is the problem. Do instead:

```
    level_moving_blocks = [
        MovingPlatform(STONE_PLATFORM_MIDDLE, 1, 0, 1350, 280, 0, 
                       0, 1350, 1600), 
        MovingPlatform(STONE_PLATFORM_MIDDLE, 0, 1, 2000, 400, 
                       300, 500, 0, 0)
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! However, could you help me with something else too?

Comment: My second platform doesn't move up and down even though I told it to in the list.

Comment: @Blazian444: maybe write up a different question with this other issue because I'm not currently sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: Well, it kind of pertains to this question to.

Comment: You know how I have change_x and change_y parameters? The first platform has a change_x of 1, and the second has a change_y of 1, but it doesn't move up and down.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be moving... sorry.

Comment: It's okay. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. I just put the boundaries in the wrong place so the platform couldn't move lol